# Category Arabic Slug shows as symbols in plugin lists

Tags: plugins, permalinks

I hope someone can help me with this issue

https://s3.amazonaws.com/sproperty1/ninjaform/Screenshot_2.png

This is a real estate plugin and it has a category for the Listing type

https://s3.amazonaws.com/sproperty1/ninjaform/Screenshot_3.png

How I can make this slug to show in the list with Arabic words. I have inspected the code and it was like this.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/sproperty1/ninjaform/Screenshot_4.png

Comment: I am not sure but it could have to with transliteration, maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18928038) could help you on your way? Maybe some info [here](https://yoast.com/ask-yoast-slug-for-arabic-urls/) helps you also a little more to understand the why/how.

Comment: I have reviewed the link and there's no solution there .... It needs a superman in WordPress Specaily with this new version.

Comment: Anyone can help .....!!!